# Using map and filter/reduce to count how many times things come up in a sequence (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, count, reduce

I need to make a list of 50 random colours, then count how many times each colour has come up in that sequence. the only way i have found to do this is as shown below:

```
colours = [ "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "White", "Black" ]
numbers = map(lambda x : random.randint(0,7), range(50))
randomcolours = map(lambda i: colours[i], numbers)
print randomcolours
x=collections.Counter(randomcolours)
print x
```

but i need to do it so i use map and filter or reduce.. i can't work out how to do it this way ?

Comment: So you're asking how to implement `collections.Counter` using `reduce()`?  Is that your question?  What part of the `reduce` documentation is confusing?  Can you provide specific quotes or references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
random_colors = [random.choice(colors) for x in range(50)]

#because python's lambda is crappy, an extra local/global function must be defined
def count_color(di, color):
    di.setdefault(color, 0)
    di[color] = di[color]+1
    return di

result = reduce(count_color, random_colors, {})
#The result is what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.choice()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/random.html#random.choice) to populate your `random_colors` list:

```
random_colors = [random.choice(colors) for x in range(50)]
```

And then one way to count all the occurances using `map()` and `filter()` can be:

```
c = dict(map(lambda to_filter: (to_filter, len(filter(lambda x: to_filter == x, random_colors))), colors))
```